# R function which converts the time of the day to the total minutes

Tags: r, function, user-defined-functions, date-conversion

I have to write my own R function "time", which converts the time of the day(in "hh:mm:ss") in hours, minutes or seconds. The daytime and the wished conversion time("h","m","s") is an argument/input. At example, if you want call the function with the arguments "05:37:26", "m" the result should be 337.4333 minutes.

I'm a total newbie and overwhelmed with writing own functions, can anybody give me a hint?

Comment: One word of advice: don't name the function "time" as there's an existing function of that name. A good introduction to writing functions [is here](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/functions.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is a homework question and we are looking for a simple function that relies on string parsing and arithmetic rather than using existing date-time functionality in R, the steps we can take are:

1. Specify your function as taking two arguments; one for the string containing the time you wish to parse, and one for the units you want to convert to. We can call these arguments `daytime` and `units`
2. Split the `daytime` string at the colons using `strsplit` and `unlist` the result. In your example, this will turn the input string `"05:37:26"` into the character vector `c("05", "37", "26")`
3. Convert this vector into numeric values using `as.numeric`
4. Multiply this result by the vector `c(3600, 60, 1)` and get the `sum` of the result. This will be the number of seconds you will use for your answer.
5. Divide the number of seconds by either 3600, 60 or 1 depending on whether the `units` argument is `"h"`, `"m"` or `"s"`. You can get this by using the `match` function.

Putting all this together, we have the following short function:

```r
time <- function(daytime, units) {
  sec <- sum(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(daytime, ":"))) * c(3600, 60, 1))
  sec / c(3600, 60, 1)[match(units, c("h", "m", "s"))]
}
```

Testing this, we have:

```r
time("05:37:26", "m")
#> [1] 337.4333

time("05:37:26", "h")
#> [1] 5.623889
```

Answer (score 0):

Beginnings are hard. Something like this. The simplest version without error monitoring. Please check the correctness of the recalculation.

```
my.time.function <- function(h, m, s) {
  hours <- s / (60 ^ 2) + m / 60 + h
  minutes <- s / 60 + m + h * 60 
  seconds <- s + m * 60 + h * 60 ^ 2
  return(list('hours' = hours, 'minutes' = minutes, 'seconds' = seconds))
}

my.time.function(5, 36, 26)
my.time.function(5, 36, 26)$minutes
```

Comment: That will fail for two Sundays in the year which have 23 and 25 hours, respectively.  A saner way is to construct 'midnight' at the same day and use time difference (which at the R level can even be asked for units).  (And it is partly OPs fault for posing this without an underlying date -- one should not.)

Comment: I said, that is the simplest version without any error monitoring :-D I assumed it's a homework. So just need a little bit to guide and finish himself. Otherwise I would use the built-in functions.

Comment: Fair enough, and agreed on builtins / library functions wjere available.